# How many active registered Cessna 172s are there in each United States state

Tags: cessna-172

This is for a school project on different aircraft accidents. (My sources I have been given are the FAA and the NTSB.

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE. You're more likely to get good answers if you demonstrate how you've attempted to find some solution yourself. Have you dived into the websites for those 2 agencies? Tried specific search terms on the internet? Looked at the manufacturer's website or a forum for owners of these aircraft? If you're part way there, someone here may be able to offer advice to get you the rest of the way, but not so many are likely to be interested in turning your research project into their research project.

Answer (score 5):

> How many active registered Cessna 172s are there in each United States state

You can use the FAA registry. E.g. to get all 172:

- Go to this [inquiry page](https://registry.faa.gov/aircraftinquiry/Search/MakeModelInquiry)
- Enter `Cessna` and `172`, press <kbd>`Submit</kbd>.
- Get the Excel file and sum all variants.

Enter `172S` if you want to have only the 172S variant, etc.

[image]